# Adonis api mail not working (adonis install @adonisjs/mail)

Tags: javascript, rest, email, smtp, adonis.js

### Problem

Hi all, I am developing Adonis restful API services  ( version 4.0). I am using adonis mail in my code. I have followed doc but I got an error like  this  :   Cannot find module 'Adonis/Src/View'

### Tools

Webstorm & insomina ( rest client )

### My folder structure

[image: structure]

#### Sample Code

```
 config/Mail.js  - I am using mailtrap

 'use strict'

 const Env = use('Env')

 module.exports = {

 connection: Env.get('MAIL_CONNECTION', 'smtp'),
 smtp: {
 driver: 'smtp',
 pool: true,
 port: 2525,
 host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
 secure: false,
 auth: {
  user: "########",
  pass: "########"
},
maxConnections: 5,
maxMessages: 100,
rateLimit: 10
  },


sparkpost: {
  driver: 'sparkpost',
   apiKey: Env.get('SPARKPOST_API_KEY'),
   extras: {}
  }
   }
```

---

```
my Code : in user controller
 // Store the information

async store({request, response}) {

let validation = await  validate(request.all(), rules)
if (validation.fails()) {
  return response.status(400).json({data: 'error', message: validation._errorMessages[0].message, status: false})
}
const userInfo = request.all();
const users = new User();
users.username = userInfo.username;
users.email = userInfo.email;
users.password = userInfo.password;
let checkUser = await dataBase.table('users').where('email', '=', users.email)
if (checkUser.length > 0) {
  return response.status(400).json({data: 'insert fail', message: 'email already register', status: false})
}
await users.save();
// sending mail after registration
const data =request.only(['username','email', 'password']);
await Mail.send('emails.welcome', {}, (message) => {
  message.from('#####.com')
  message.to('####.com')
})
return response.status(201).json({message: 'user created successfull', status: true});
```

}

#### Screenshots - Rest client

[image: error]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its asking to view provider need to install after that only welcome html file will be work

need to register the view provider inside the providers array

```
'@adonisjs/framework/providers/ViewProvider'
```

Comment: Didn't solve the issue for me, there's more to it in 2021. My answer below did.

Answer (score 1):

I was still getting this error after registering the `ViewProvider`.

Turns out the latest versions Mail and Validation packages (potentially others too) have breaking changes to work with Adonis version 5. To install the version of each package that work with Adonis version 4.1, use the legacy flag while installing through with npm.

Like so: `npm i @adonisjs/mail@legacy`

Read more on the subject from the maintainers [here](https://github.com/adonisjs/mail/issues/60#issuecomment-808339684)